# 'TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable' in oTree Page error_message

Tags: python, otree

I am trying to compare a code that an individual put in a form field with a list of codes that I have to put, but I get the next error

```
Internal Server Error: /p/75spo3h2/beliefs/Code/1/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\diese\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site- 
packages\otree\forms\forms.py", line 252, in _clean_fields
error_string = error_message_method(value)
File "C:\Users\diese\beliefs\beliefs\pages.py", line 15, in 
number_error_message
if value[("numbers")] not in [int(1234, 3456, 6986)]:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
ERROR Internal Server Error: /p/75spo3h2/beliefs/Code/1/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\diese\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site- 
packages\otree\forms\forms.py", line 252, in _clean_fields
error_string = error_message_method(value)
  File "C:\Users\diese\beliefs\beliefs\pages.py", line 15, in 
number_error_message 
if value[("numbers")] not in [int(1234, 3456, 6986)]:
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable
```

I tried changing the numbers to int but that doesn't work well

```
class Code(Page):
    form_model = 'player'
    form_fields = ['number']

    def number_error_message(self, value):
        print('El número que pusiste es', value)
        if value[("numbers")] not in [1234, 3456, 6986]:
           return 'El código debe corresponder al código que se le entrego en la sesión 1'
```

Comment: How and where is `number_error_message` called? Can you show the entire code of `Code`?

Answer (score 0):

The error message generating method in `Page` you can override in your subclass is called `error_message`. It receives a dictionary `values` which contains the values of all `form_fields` in the page.

In your case, this will be a dictionary with a single entry, as you only have a single field, e.g. if the player entered `123` it will be:

```
values = {"number": 123}
```

Hence, the following should be the correct implementation:

```
class Code(Page):
    form_model = 'player'
    form_fields = ['number']

    def error_message(self, values):
        print('El número que pusiste es', values["number"])
        if values["number"] not in [1234, 3456, 6986]:
             return 'El código debe corresponder al código que se le entrego en la sesión 1'
```